What is python equivalent of qweibull in MathCAD?
I want to get the x value for the given quantile while the data is weibull distributed. Mathcad has qweibull and scipy has scipy.stats.norm.ppf(q) for normal distribution.
However, I dont find scipy.stats.weibull.ppf(q, c)
How can I achieve this?

I believe the matching function in SciPy is called scipy.stats.weibull_min and it implements the scipy.stats.weibull_min.ppf(q, c) as well.
Formula from MathCad docs:

Formula from SciPy docs:

